# PowerBI Percent Average Different Than Excel Average

Tags: excel, powerbi

I'm moving from an old Excel based reporting system to PowerBI and I'm finding some discrepancies.

When I take the same listed percentages in PowerBI and calculate the average in excel, it's different (See Below):

I have no idea what's going on here... I thought maybe it was a rounding issue, but it's just not making sense to me.

When I export the PowerBI data from the table and then average it in excel it's a different number.

That shouldn't happen, right?

Am I going crazy here?

[image: ExcelWTF]

[image: PowerBIWTF]

When I calculate it manually I get `99.828%` which should round to `99.83%` as Excel shows.

It seems to me that the PowerBI average is simply incorrect.

**Edit:**

After applying RADO's answer, here are my results (I dropped the Round and it seems to work - I think maybe it's an issue with my data - not his methodology):

[image: Yay]

Comment: Is the precision (not just the displayed values) of the exported Excel data the same as the data in PowerBI ?  Most likely the two calculations are not based on the exact same data.

Comment: I thought this too @TimWilliams but yes. Both tables are rounded to 2 decimal places. I even tried manually rounding the power bi data in the formula and it didn't work either. Regardless, power bi should round the average using the rounding in the table so it should match the table's numbers, right?

Comment: If I export the data and average the export it should match, right? I can't imagine a reason it shouldn't.

Comment: No idea - it does seem like the underlying data may differ, but i don't have PoweBI (or access to your data) so I'm unable to test.  You should note that if your use ROUND() on a worksheet it's not the same as (eg) using Round() in VBA (and possibly in other languages): https://wellsr.com/vba/2017/excel/what-you-need-to-know-about-the-vba-round-function/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a critical difference between how Excel and DAX calculate averages.

Excel takes average of the rounded numbers in each row.

DAX (Power BI) calculates averages **independently in each cell**. Meaning that cell "total" is calculated not as average of rounded scores, but as average of non-rounded underlying values of the entire data set, which is then rounded. This is how DAX operates conceptually - each calculation is always done independently of other calculations in the table.

The way to fix it: 
In Power BI, rewrite you DAX formula to use AVERAGEX instead of AVERAGE. For example:

```
Correctly Averaged Scores = 
    AVERAGEX(
        VALUES(TableName[Submitter]),
        ROUND(CALCULATE(AVERAGE(TableName[OrbScore])),2)
)
```

Here, we first create a list of distinct "Submitters". Then we iterate over the list, and for each submitter calculate its average and round it to 2 digits. Finally, we calculate the average of the rounded averages, essentially replicating the behaviour of Excel.